# Django - UniqueConstraint not created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to enforce a constraint for `mysql` where user is prohibited from inserting twice the same `name` and `model`. E.g This should not be allowed to be inserted twice: `name:Name1 model:Model1`

```
#Model
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#View
class CarListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        trip_code = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return Car.objects.filter(trip = trip_code) #Return cars for given trip

#Seializer
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('__all__')
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'model'], name='car_name_model_constraint')
        ]
```

The problem is that the constraint is never created and thus not enforced. What might be the issue with the code?

Comment: The constraint needs to be added to the model not the serializer

Comment: The model is created without a constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unique_together in class Meta in Model like that:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name','model']
```

More on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Thank you. That was a silly mistake.

Comment: Also this is the same as adding the `UniqueConstraint`  on the model instead of `unique_together`

Comment: Yeah, I just think it's more clear in code to do it this way